# Gatsby deployment to Netlify failing using bit.dev remote server

Tags: javascript, web, gatsby, netlify, bit.dev

I'm building my first site on Netlify. I haven't changed my gatsby site in weeks. When I tried to deploy live, I'm getting build errors.

I'm getting the following issues when deploying. Both gatsby build and gatsby develop work for me locally, so I'm confused as to why I'm getting the error.

Everything is up to date and it works locally, so I'm stuck as to where to go from here.

```
10:36:03 PM: Build ready to start
10:36:06 PM: build-image version: 9cade8af58c2cf3a17a1e9433d2e979149488837
10:36:06 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.5
10:36:06 PM: buildbot version: 2fd8f04962d5dbc77b79b9c2f5ab7a077e87376b
10:36:07 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:36:07 PM: Starting to download cache of 144.7MB
10:36:09 PM: Finished downloading cache in 2.582825701s
10:36:09 PM: Starting to extract cache
10:36:15 PM: Finished extracting cache in 6.000055876s
10:36:15 PM: Finished fetching cache in 8.709880759s
10:36:15 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:36:16 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/branchone
10:36:16 PM: Starting build script
10:36:16 PM: Installing dependencies
10:36:17 PM: Started restoring cached node version
10:36:19 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
10:36:20 PM: v10.19.0 is already installed.
10:36:21 PM: Now using node v10.19.0 (npm v6.13.4)
10:36:22 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
10:36:24 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
10:36:24 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
10:36:24 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:36:24 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:36:24 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.13.4
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/log-update-c8270e83/license'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-fetch-7939c3a5/CHANGELOG.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/log-update-c8270e83/index.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/lodash.clonedeep-be5c4aa2/package.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/js-base64-e442654a/package.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-fetch-7939c3a5/LICENSE.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/log-update-c8270e83/package.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/lodash.clonedeep-be5c4aa2/README.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/js-base64-e442654a/1x1.png'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-fetch-7939c3a5/README.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/log-update-c8270e83/readme.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/lodash.clonedeep-be5c4aa2/LICENSE'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/js-base64-e442654a/base64.html'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/log-update-c8270e83/index.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/lodash.clonedeep-be5c4aa2/index.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/js-base64-e442654a/base64.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-fetch-7939c3a5/browser.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/tar-f1740c72/.nyc_output/37d58de4-deea-4808-bb77-d27685bd1501.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-graphiql-explorer-a88a8607/index.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/background-attachment.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/tar-f1740c72/.nyc_output/5ad8066b-6b8c-4bc8-b807-c40bf80898b7.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-graphiql-explorer-a88a8607/package.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/background-clip-text.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/tar-f1740c72/.nyc_output/5cbf674c-7089-4b7d-b9de-2119be4dbb0b.json'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-graphiql-explorer-a88a8607/CHANGELOG.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/background-img-opts.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/dist/schema/context.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree-cb081d4c/dist/create-program/shared.d.ts.map'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-graphiql-explorer-a88a8607/README.md'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/dist/utils/create-node-id.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/styled-components-c1c1797b/dist/styled-components.min.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/parser-4551b83e/lib/tokenizer/index.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/background-position-x-y.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/core-c498252d/lib/config/files/types.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree-cb081d4c/dist/create-program/shared.js.map'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/preset-env-d3eb7fcc/lib/polyfills/corejs2/entry-plugin.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/background-repeat-round-space.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/core-c498252d/lib/config/util.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/preset-env-d3eb7fcc/lib/polyfills/corejs3/entry-plugin.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/background-sync.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/core-c498252d/lib/config/files/utils.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/client/utils/log.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/battery-status.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/lib/utils/normalizeOptions.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree-cb081d4c/dist/ts-estree/ts-estree.d.ts.map'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/bin/options.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/cache-dir/commonjs/create-react-context.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils-0f843c2d/dist/eslint-utils/applyDefault.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/client/overlay.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/cache-dir/create-react-context.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/lib/utils/processOptions.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/dist/utils/create-schema-customization.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils-0f843c2d/dist/eslint-utils/batchedSingleLineTests.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/client/utils/reloadApp.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/lib/utils/routes.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/preset-env-d3eb7fcc/lib/polyfills/corejs2/get-platform-specific-default.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/ink-d906e9af/build/experimental/dom.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/beacon.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/lib/utils/runBonjour.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/beforeafterprint.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/lib/utils/runOpen.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils-0f843c2d/dist/eslint-utils/deepMerge.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/webpack-dev-server-ad2d41fe/client/utils/sendMessage.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/dist/schema/types/date.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils-0f843c2d/dist/eslint-utils/getParserServices.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils-0f843c2d/dist/eslint-utils/index.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-releases-ab6f917e/.idea/encodings.xml'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/cache-dir/commonjs/default-html.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-releases-ab6f917e/.idea/misc.xml'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/cache-dir/default-html.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/ink-d906e9af/build/experimental/output.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/bigint.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-releases-ab6f917e/.idea/modules.xml'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/dist/schema/types/derived-types.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/loglevel-b5b4bfec/lib/loglevel.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-releases-ab6f917e/.idea/inspectionProfiles'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/dist/utils/detect-port-in-use-and-prompt.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/gatsby-6b1ce8d7/cache-dir/__tests__/dev-loader.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/ink-d906e9af/build/experimental/reconciler.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-releases-ab6f917e/.idea/vcs.xml'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/preset-env-d3eb7fcc/lib/polyfills/corejs3/shipped-proposals.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/blobbuilder.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/node-releases-ab6f917e/.idea/workspace.xml'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM:  WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/bloburls.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/preset-env-d3eb7fcc/lib/polyfills/corejs2/usage-plugin.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@babel/preset-env-d3eb7fcc/lib/polyfills/corejs3/usage-plugin.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/ink-d906e9af/build/experimental/renderer.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils-0f843c2d/dist/ts-eslint/Rule.d.ts'
10:36:38 PM: npm
10:36:38 PM: WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/border-image.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/border-radius.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-react-2ba72860/lib/util/jsx.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/broadcastchannel.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-react-2ba72860/lib/util/linkComponents.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/caniuse-lite-12aab0cf/data/features/brotli.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:40 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:36:38 PM: tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-react-2ba72860/lib/util/log.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN tar
10:36:38 PM:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/fsevents-b86bc582/node_modules/nopt/LICENSE'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
10:36:40 PM: Shutting down logging, 492 messages pending
10:36:38 PM:  tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/.staging/eslint-plugin-react-2ba72860/lib/util/makeNoMethodSetStateRule.js'
10:36:38 PM: npm WARN
```

Comment: Do you have a github repository link we can fork and test?

Are you build settings correct on netlify

Repository: github.com/luke/{yourRepoName}
Base directory: Not set  |
Build command: gatsby build |
Publish directory: public/  |
Deploy log visibility: Logs are public  |

Comment: Is your Gatsby installation in the root of your repository folder? package.json should be on the same level as your .git folder (not in a subfolder).

Comment: @StefanT here is a link: https://github.com/lukebyrne73/lukesnewsite

Comment: @AlbertSkibinski here is a link to the repo, it looks like it's in the right folder: https://github.com/lukebyrne73/lukesnewsite

Comment: @Luke I don't see anything that has to do with bit.dev in the repository you shared.

Comment: @itaymendel the op changed all the errors to the next issue he was having, so this is now a rolling question  https://github.com/lukebyrne73/lukesnewsite/commit/ab1863f34a1b0ce0d20b2be287f2affebea53328

Answer (score 2):

The culprit here is the use of a `bit.dev` component registry server for one of your dependencies.

```js
    "@bit/bondz.react-epic-spinners.atom-spinner": "^0.3.0",
```

[Here is the doc section](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/ci#netlify) to start following to setup on Netlify:

> On Netlify, you cannot generate the file dynamically, and you should [add .npmrc file in your project](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/ci#add-npmrc-to-the-project).

## Add .npmrc to the project

You can add a `.npmrc` in your project with the following:

`/.npmrc`

```sh
@bit:registry=https://node.bit.dev
//node.bit.dev/:_authToken=${BIT_TOKEN}
always-auth=true
```

> Add the BIT_TOKEN as [environment variable](https://www.netlify.com/docs/continuous-deployment/#environment-variables)

**DO NOT:** replace the `BIT_TOKEN` variable with the actual token in the `.npmrc` file because it is public. Only put the token into the admin panel of Netlify explained in the linked docs.

Comment: Thanks Talves. To test this, I removed the bit.dev component and dependency, but the deploy still failed.  updated my question with the new logs

Comment: Unfortunately, what you did was replace one issue with another. This is now another (different issue) that had nothing to do with the original problem.